# OAuth 2.0 with SpringSecurity. after successful get of the token no access

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I get token post request to http://localhost:8090/oauth/token with Headers:
Basic Y2xpZW50OnF3ZXJ0eQ== (for username:client and password:qwerty) and params: username:user
password:123
grant_type:password

```
{
    "access_token": "6595cfb6-e79c-4110-adc1-eb5e0926bd74",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "2036efc5-b1a9-4d50-9fc8-4c0746737732",
    "expires_in": 299,
    "scope": "read write trust"
}
```

and in the next step I try to get access to localhost:8090/test/0 , but I get :

```
{
    "timestamp": 1523824850474,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
    "path": "/test/0"
}
```

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong
in my AuthorizationServerConfig:

```
@Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("client")
                .secret("qwerty")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(300)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.realm("REALM");
    }
```

ResourceServer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

And SecurityConfig:

```
@Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("123").roles("ADMIN").and()
                .withUser("user").password("123").roles("USER");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .realmName("REALM");
    }


    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore){
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }
```

I don't understand why this does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you're getting it appears that you are not using the access token correctly to make a request.
Add an `Authorization`header and access token with `bearer` perfix as its value.

[image]